# Parse iOS SDK + Cloud Code: Error: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-framework

I am trying out Cloud Code for the first time and I've run into some trouble. I think I have most of this right. I'm trying to add a user's "ID" to another user's object at an array called "likes". The code I'm using is...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("lifeLike", function(request, response) {

    var userID = request.params.userID;
    var selectedFriendID = request.params.selectedFriendID;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("userID", selectedFriendID);
    query.find().then(function (users) {

        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

        users.add("likes", userID);

        users.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
        }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
        });


    }, function (error) {

        response.error(error);

    });

});
```

when I call it in iOS

```
 [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"like" withParameters:

                @ {

                    @"userID": [PFUser currentUser][@"userID"],
                    @"selectedFriendID": self.selectedFriendID

                }

                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {

                    if (error) {

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to like this user.\n%@", [error userInfo][@"error"]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                        [alert show];
                    }

                    else {

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Liked" message:@"You now like this user." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                        [alert show];
                    }

            }];
```

i get this error

```
Error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'add'
```

This is my first time trying Cloud Code. Can anybody help me out with why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.find() returns an array with the results which doesn't have a method add().If you're only searching for one user, try using .first() which returns one object.